# Nodejs and Wordpress both port 80 virtualhost configuration on Mac

Tags: node.js, wordpress, apache, server, virtualhost

I am currently running my node.js web app on port 80 on my Mac with domain www.aaa.com, 
But now I want to add a Wordpress(Apache) on 80 on this Mac machine too with domain www.bbb.com,
how do I configure the virtualhost? I tried many researches on the internet, but no luck , can anyone tell me how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can have multiple public IP addresses, you just need to:

- map each of the domains to a different IP address
- have node.js and Apache listen on one of the IP addresses each

If not (you only have a single IP address), you'll need to have one of the two servers take port 80 and forward/proxy the data to the other (listening on a separate port) for its requests. Or, alternatively, use a reverse proxy (such as pound) to do this job (you then have the reverse proxy on port 80, and both node.js and Apache on other ports).

Comment: I'm just trying to use vhost in apache to do this proxy, so do you think that would work? I did a lot of try but failed, I might continue researching on it if it is doable.

Comment: Definitely can. If you have issues with it, open a new question with the relevant details of your configuration and the actual issues you have. Remember, node.js will need to run on a different port, and you will need to have two virtual hosts in Apache, one that sends to Wordpress, the other that proxies to node.js.